# Unity Lifetime Managers & EF Data Context --> Best Practice

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container, httprequest

All,

There has been a lot of posts about Unity Lifetime Managers but I have yet to find someone state a good rule of thumb for "in these cases you should always use X".  Let me describe my application, I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application.  I have a Visual Studio solution containing 3 projects, my 'Core' project which has all of my EF stuff, a testing project, and the MVC Web Project.  I am using Unity for dependency injection and have the following code right now:

```
// Context
container.RegisterType<IDatabaseFactory, DatabaseFactory>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager();
container.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

However, I'm noticing that my context is not recreated with every new web request which is what I think I would want (let me know if I'm wrong in that assumption).  I'm having a hard time analyzing all of the information from the sites listed below and have read about a lot of people creating their own class named PerHttpRequestLifetimeManager to handle this.

What truly is the best practice here?

1. Understanding Lifetime Managers by Microsoft's Developer Network - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=PandP.20).aspx
2. MVC DI & Unity with Lifetime Manager via CodeProject - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424743/MVC-DI-Unity-with-Lifetime-Manager
3. ASP.NET MVC Tip: Dependency Injection with Unity Application Block via Shiju Varghese's Blog - http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2008/10/24/asp-net-mvc-tip-dependency-injection-with-unity-application-block.aspx
4. MVC, EF - DataContext singleton instance Per-Web-Request in Unity via Stack Overflow - [MVC, EF - DataContext singleton instance Per-Web-Request in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187562/mvc-ef-datacontext-singleton-instance-per-web-request-in-unity)
5. Inject same DataContext instance across several types with Unity via Stack Overflow - [Inject same DataContext instance across several types with Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897205/inject-same-datacontext-instance-across-several-types-with-unity)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585478/one-dbcontext-per-web-request-why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you usually want one DbContext per request.

A PerHttpRequestLifetimeManager or child container created on every request are the typical ways this is handled.

The latest release of [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170416.aspx) introduces the [Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) which has a new built-in lifetime manager: `PerRequestLifetimeManager`.

You can read more in the [Developer's Guide to Dependency Injection Using Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) chapter 3, [Dependency Injection with Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx).

Comment: Hey Randy! A bit old answer but my problem is really related to this. I'm using `PerRequestLifetimeManager` to register my context in Unity: `container.RegisterType<DbContext, EntitiesContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());` - but the DbContext is never disposed in a per request basis. I also included this line in the `RegisterTypes` method: `DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));` but when I do that, the DbContext is disposed before the request ends. Any ideas?