# Enum stored correctly in DB but not being deserialized into type correctly in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, enums, ef-code-first

I have an enum:

```
public enum EnumSample{
    Setup = 1,
    Pending = 7
}
```

I have an entity (I'm using EF) stored in the database with its `EnumSample` property set to `EnumSample.Pending`.  The database reflects this value as `7` when I query.  However when I retrieve the same entity from within C# (using EF), I get an incorrect type mapping (I'm getting `Setup` when I should be getting `Pending`).  All IDs are validated.  Screenshot below.  What could be causing this?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Restarting the app gets me what I expect - the issue is that the instance of dbContext is sticking around between requests.  I can do `using var db = new AppContext` and it works fine.

I have the following configured on my `UnityContainer`:

```
   container.RegisterType<AppContext>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

I've tried various different lifetime managers - `PerHttpRequestLifetimeManager` doesn't resolve per other guidance I've seen.

An example of a service layer method:

```
   public class EventService : BaseService
   {

    public readonly AppContext _db;

    private readonly NotificationService _notificationService;

    public EventService(AppContext db, NotificationService notificationService)
    {
        _db = db;
        _notificationService = notificationService;
    }
```

The behavior that I need is that `EventService` and `NotificationService` have the same instance of `AppContext`, but that between requests, the context is disposed and I get fresh state / new instance.

Comment: Could you perhaps use profiler or Extended Events and see how query generated by Entity Framework actually looks like? We could then use it to verify if it yields the same result as the one you used to check on database.

Comment: Are you using Code first?

Comment: @vendettamit I am.  I'm discovering that if I restart the app, I get what I expected.  I believe it's something to do with a stale dbContext...

Comment: Are you sure you are not just setting the property yourself?Add a breakpoint on the setter

Comment: Look at the lifecycle of the context. The best strategy is to use per request  context in web app.

Comment: @vendettamit I'm fairly certain that's it.  Are you familiar with Unity?  If so I can rework this question.  I'm trying `container.RegisterType<AppContext>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());` and getting the same results.

Comment: Sure, Go ahead!! If I'm not than some one will surely can review it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PerThreadLifetimeManager` doesn't guarantee that each request will served by different thread. Unity doesn't have per request life time manager by default. You need to install a nuget package [Unity.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) which has a new built-in lifetime manager: `PerRequestLifetimeManager`.

@SB2055 See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18264598/881798) for more details.

Comment: That was exactly it.  You're incredible - thanks for the help.